# rails unique many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, unique

I am using rails 4 and have a many to many relationship using `:has_many :through` and I am trying to ensure that the join is unique such that a particular film and tag does not join each other more than once. by using `validates_uniqueness_of` I have achieved this between saves however if two or more of the same tags are added in one update the uniqueness is not ensured. please find below the relevant code:

```
class Film < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :film_tags, inverse_of: :film, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, -> {uniq}, through: :film_tags

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :film_tags, allow_destroy: true
end

class FilmTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :film, inverse_of: :film_tags
  belongs_to :tag, inverse_of: :film_tags, counter_cache: true

  validates_uniqueness_of :tag_id, scope: :film_id, message: "duplicate tag"
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :film_tags, inverse_of: :tag, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :films, -> {uniq}, through: :film_tags

  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

I have tried adding a `before_save` to film where `film.film_tags` had `.uniq` run against it (also tried `uniq{|film_tag| film_tag.tag_id}`) but this just removes all `film_tag` joins but 1 even if some tags were not duplicated.

Can anyone provide help with this issue? Alternatively if more information is required please ask.

Comment: I think you are looking for the unique index constraint on the db. This article might help you http://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happening because uniqueness validation tries to find a duplicate record, In this case for both the tags there is no record present in the actual DB. So both passes the validation and creates the tags in the DB.

I faced a similar issue in the past.

But I have used the approach mentioned in the following blog.

https://techbrownbags.wordpress.com/2014/02/05/rails-validation-of-cocoon-nested-forms/

Hope it helps.